# Is Magento2 over-complicated, over-engineered, and bloated?

Tags: magento2

Does it really take this much code to display a product title on a product detail page with Magento2?

[image]

And then that much code for pretty much every other piece of information that displays on each page? And then a never ending folder structure full of tiny files that reference other tiny files.

I understand it's very flexible and generating and caching static files but why so much code just to display one field from a database?

And then something the h1 which should be set in an admin setting tag is hard coded... it seems on the surface that it wasn't thought out very well and over-coded for theme developer flexibility instead of actual users.

I'm thrilled with the potential flexibility but it takes way too much time and effort to become a real end user / developer :(

Comment: Well...there's a lot more going on there than 'just displaying one field', mostly in the interest of flexibility and extensibility. That's all it boils down to.

Comment: I gave a presentation about responsibilities in templates a couple of times. Perhaps it might be of interest to some: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1h7KKZPVEUEZUW0QgN3AtTSSYH1YSGECXi7D0vBW6FyE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: yeah Magento is terrible